# jQuery: How to get the HTTP status code from within the $.ajax.error method?

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery to make an AJAX request. I want to perform different actions whether or not the HTTP status code is a 400 error or a 500 error. How can I achieve this?

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/controller/action',
    data: $form.serialize(),
    success: function(data){
        alert('horray! 200 status code!');
    },
    error: function(data){
        //get the status code
        if (code == 400) {
            alert('400 status code! user error');
        }
        if (code == 500) {
            alert('500 status code! server error');
        }
    },
});
```

### Update:

@GeorgeCummins mentioned that it "seemed odd" to work with the response body. This is the first time that I've attempted doing this sort of thing. Is my approach not a best-practice? What would you recommend? I created another StackOverflow question for this here: [What response/status code should I send to an AJAX request when there is a user/form validation error?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6701376/48523)

Answer (score 111, accepted):

If you're using jQuery 1.5, then `statusCode` will work.

If you're using jQuery 1.4, try this:

```
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(jqXHR.status);
    alert(textStatus);
    alert(errorThrown);
}
```

You should see the status code from the first alert.

Comment: Oh, I see my problem. I was thinking that `data` was being passed to the error method, but it's actually `jqXHR`, `textStatus`, and `errorThrown`

Comment: I like your answer because you mention the differences between the different versions of jQuery, which I didn't notice at first.

Comment: I'm using your example at jQ 2.x and status is always zero (0),  textStatus always 'error' and  errorthrown is empty. Any ideas? What I have done: Turn of the server after the page is loaded to figure out what happen.

Comment: It worked for me when I got the status code 419 and I could handle the error.

Answer (score 69):

You should create a map of actions using the `statusCode` setting:

```
$.ajax({
  statusCode: {
    400: function() {
      alert('400 status code! user error');
    },
    500: function() {
      alert('500 status code! server error');
    }
  }
});
```

[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) (Scroll to: 'statusCode')

**EDIT** (In response to comments)

If you need to take action based on the data returned in the response body (which seems odd to me), you will need to use `error:` instead of `statusCode:`

```
error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
    switch (xhr.status) {
        case 404:
             // Take action, referencing xhr.responseText as needed.
    }
}
```

Comment: I started down that route, but couldn't figure out how to get the data. How do you access the response body?

Comment: @Andrew: Why do you need to access the response body? Are you expecting useful data to be returned when a 400 or 500 error occurs?

Comment: Yes, I'm using a status code of 400 for form validation errors. (not sure if that is appropriate or not)

Comment: In that case, can you take the appropriate form validation action in the body of the `400: function() {`. Just remove the alert() and add the necessary code.

Comment: the response body contains the html of the error messages. How can I access the request body from within the `400: function() {`?

Comment: @GeorgeCummins let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1486/discussion-between-andrew-and-george-cummins)

Comment: Why is it odd to tell the caller of the API what the exact problem is rather than just telling them 400.

Answer (score 16):

An other solution is to use the response.status function. This will give you the http status wich is returned by the ajax call.

```
function checkHttpStatus(url) {     
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        data: {},
        url: url,
        error: function(response) {
            alert(url + " returns a " + response.status);
        }, success() {
            alert(url + " Good link");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: this solution is best

Comment: this answer assumes that the first argument to the `error` handler is the `response` (as for the `success` handler), but this it not the case: the first argument is the `jqXHR`

Answer (score 9):

use

```
   statusCode: {
    404: function() {
      alert('page not found');
    }
  }
```

-

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/controller/action',
    data: $form.serialize(),
    success: function(data){
        alert('horray! 200 status code!');
    },
    statusCode: {
    404: function() {
      alert('page not found');
    },

    400: function() {
       alert('bad request');
   }
  }

});
```

Comment: how would you catch an unexpected statusCode, is there a catch-all or else handler in this version of the syntax?

Answer (score 0):

> Here you can use this too it works for me

```
$.ajax({
  success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
    console.log(xhr.status);
  },
  complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {
    console.log(xhr.status);
  } 
});
```