# Jquery ajax error handler function exists, but still an exception thrown

Tags: jquery, ajax, exception, error-handling

I submit a form using ajax, and the validation is done on server side.
If validation fails I return a json encoded object with the errors and status code: 500.
When on client side jquery gets the response my error handler function is called and it works perfectly, BUT
(probably this is a normal behavior) an exception is thrown in Chrome (probably other browser too):

```
POST http://localhost/workplace/.../clients/create 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

This makes me and probably my clients 'feel' that my program isn't working correctly, but there is just a validation error.
How to handle this situation?

Comment: Why are you returning a 500 status code?

Comment: If validation fails on server side, I want on client side my errorHandler to be called. Why 500? For now, just form testing..what status code should I use?

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6701376/what-response-status-code-should-i-send-to-an-ajax-request-when-there-is-a-user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't return a 500 (Internal Server Error) Code. This is to indicate that is something wrong with the server (not with the request). This is probably what is causing the exception. I believe that is fine to return a 200 (OK) code. You don't need to reflect the validation error in the HTTP status code.