# Fetch http status code in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

Below is an existing jquery code in our code base.

```
$("#download_").click( function() {
    $("#error").html('');
    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        cache : false,
        async : false,
        url : "/download",
        success : function(data) {
            var json_obj = $.parseJSON(data);
            if(json_obj !== undefined && json_obj != null){
                if(json_obj.download=="success"){
                    location=json_obj.url;
                }
            }
        },
        error : function(data) {
            // TODO
            $("#error").html(failed);               
        }
    });     
});
```

Here, In case of error (marked as TODO), I want to check if the http status is 404, then I need to redirect user to different url.

Can any one tell me how do I get the http status in this error: function(data) method?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: How to get the HTTP status code from within the $.ajax.error method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6700822/jquery-how-to-get-the-http-status-code-from-within-the-ajax-error-method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you even look at the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)?

```
$.ajax({
  ...
  statusCode: {
    404: function() {
      alert('page not found');
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try: `statusCode`
from documentation:

```
$.ajax({
  statusCode: {
    404: function() {
      alert('page not found');
    }
  }
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

EDIT:

Now that I think about it, do you only want to redirect if it's a 404? What about other error codes?