# How to capture the 500 error message using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How can i capture the 500 error message using jquery? I want to keep on checking for the 500 error message for sometime until it changes and time out after 50 sec.

I used the code below to try to capture and check the 500 error message but it doesnt seem to catch the 500 error message. I can see it in the firebug

```
$.ajax({
    statusCode: {
        500: function() {
            alert(" 500 data still loading");
            console.log('500 ');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Take a look at the code used in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6700822/jquery-how-to-get-the-http-status-code-from-within-the-ajax-error-method), and also [its accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6700873/114359)

Comment: I have rolled back the question to show the original code. Please don't edit the meaning of questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you missing `url` in `$.ajax` like the one below

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/path to page",
    statusCode: {
        500: function() {
            alert(" 500 data still loading");
            console.log('500 ');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried adding url to it too that didnt work.. it hungs up the page

Comment: what do you mean by hungs up the page as i can see now your code should work now if the URL is correct

Comment: the url is correct .. but when i add the url to ajax the page stop loading as I refresh the page after submiting. but if i remove the url i can see the 500 Internal server error on fire bug .. but i am unable to alert out the 500 error message

Comment: in your code try to replace url: "somepage.html"; with this one url: "somepage.html", that should be , not ;

Comment: updated "somepage.html"; with this one url: "somepage.html",  - Thanks

Answer (score 11):

Dispite the accepted answer mentioned by @Danny, you can also do this in newer versions of jQuery.

```
var xhr = $.ajax({
    url: "somewhere"
});

xhr.fail(function(xhr, textStatus, error) {
    // Error handling stuff here ...
});
```

See [Deferred Object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).

Answer (score 3):

You can check the status in error of ajax post please check the below code.

```
 $.ajax({
        .....
        success: function (data) {

        },
        complete: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {

        },
        error: function (e, status) {

            if (e.status == 404)
                alert("404 error");
        }
    });
```

Thanks