# Javascript check web server HTTP status code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is there anyway with javascript/jQuery to check if a website is up?

You're limited by the single origin policy I don't think you can use a standard Ajax request, but is it possible to try and load a file (similar to wget) and get the status code of the reply another way?

This would be for a user side website checker, where they can check if multiple domains are "up" without having to use any code on a server.

e.g. I open a web page at `checkmysite.org` it sends an HTTP request to `mysite.org` to check whether it receives a response, and if so the domain is online

Comment: Possibly what you are searching for is implemented with ajax and get request. eg. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6700822/jquery-how-to-get-the-http-status-code-from-within-the-ajax-error-method

Comment: @JimmyKane unfortunately I don't think that will work cross domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The single origin policy exists for a very good reason. What you're asking is effectively the same as "how can I defeat the single origin policy?".

You could always work around the policy **with the co-operation of the server-end**, for some specific known server. (e.g: CORS, cross-domain.xml in flash, `<script>` tag, etc).

Why is it so important that this not have help from the server at `checkmysite.org`? It could host an absolutely trivial php script which does the `HEAD` request for you. Your JavaScript code could just do a normal `GET` request to the PHP script.