# AJAX call doesn't go into "error:" block if the API server returns http 500

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to implement a retry logic in my javascript code. This is how I'm calling the API:

```
$.ajax({
            url: api_url + 'report',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            tryCount : 0,
            retryLimit : 3,

            headers: {
                "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(api_username + ":" + api_pass)
            },

            data: {start: start_date, end: end_date},
            success: function(result) {
                data = result.results;
                console.log("success");
            },
            error : function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
                console.log("in error");
                if (textStatus == 'timeout') {
                    this.tryCount++;
                    if (this.tryCount <= this.retryLimit) {
                        //try again
                        console.log("try count:");
                        console.log(this.tryCount);
                        $.ajax(this);
                        return;
                    }            
                    return;
                }
                if (xhr.status == 500) {
                    console.log("still 500");
                } else {
                    console.log("still !500");
                }
            }
        });
```

So when there are issues with the server and it returns http 500 then still my control in the above JS file doesn't go into the "error:" block and this line: "console.log("in error");" doesnt get printed on the console.

How can I correctly implement a retry logic in my code in case my server returns 500 then it should keep on retrying for some x amount of times?

Comment: Have you tried using [statusCode](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6700873/1022914)?

Answer (score 1):

500 error generally means that something is wrong with backend server. So it doesn't get into error block of client JavaScript. I don't think there is anything you can do. But in general you can always ask backend developers to do better error handling and return apt error response if possible.