# How to get HTTP-StatusCode in ajaxError?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I try to get the HTTP error code in the generic `$(document).ajaxError()` method. How can I read it out? I found this [jQuery: How to get the HTTP status code from within the $.ajax.error method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6700822/jquery-how-to-get-the-http-status-code-from-within-the-ajax-error-method) but I don't manage to adapt it to my function.

JQuery version is 2.1.3.

```
$(document).ajaxError(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    if (jqXHR.statusCode != "500") {
        $("#global-error-wrapper").show();
        $(".global-error-message-inner-text").text(trans("noconnectionerror"));
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you post the code that has your `Ajax` call?

Comment: I have many Ajax-Calls methods, so the goal for me was to handle this generically in the ajaxError function.

Comment: Try logging the `jqXHR` object and see what's available (`console.log(jqXHR)`).  Might reveal where the information you're looking for is.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have already checked the object intensively and unfortunately I didn't find any HTTP code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using [ajaxError](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxerror/) which seems to be a bit different than the ajax event error handler defined in the settings in the link you posted. For `ajaxError()`, it looks like the first parameter in the callback is the event and the second is the jqXHR object you want. Also it should be `jqXHR.status` and not `statusCode` Try the below

```
$(document).ajaxError(function (event, jqXHR, settings, thrownError) {
    if (jqXHR.status != 500) {
        $("#global-error-wrapper").show();
        $(".global-error-message-inner-text").text(trans("noconnectionerror"));
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. Unfortunately it's "0" with `jqXHR.status`. `statusCode` returns a function map.

Comment: anything interesting when you inspect the correct jqXHR object now?

Comment: also you may be getting a response of 0 due to another problem, see if this helps this new problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000609/jquery-ajax-status-code-0

Comment: I will check that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You were right. it was another problem and .status is working. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The `statusCode` object on the `jqXHR` object in your `ajaxError` method refers to an object mapping that you can create when you build your `ajax` call. If you have an idea of what status codes to expect, you could build out this mapping and send it along with your `ajax` calls which could help you identify what status code was returned:

```
var statusCodeMapping = {
    404: function() {
        $notFound = true;
    }
}

$.ajax({
  statusCode: statusCodeMapping
});
```

You could then examine the `$notFound` object to see if that was the status code returned from your `Ajax` call:

```
$(document).ajaxError(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    if ($notFound) {
        $("#global-error-wrapper").show();
        $(".global-error-message-inner-text").text(trans("noconnectionerror"));
    }
});
```

> The `$notFound` object should be global to your script