# Error message from Java to Ajax is not returned properly

Tags: java, ajax

When the java program does not find the required information I want to return an appropriate error message (could be one of a number of identified reasons). My java code is:

```
}else{
    response.sendError(response.SC_BAD_REQUEST, "Captcha description not correct");
    response.getWriter().write("Captcha description incorrect.");
}
```

And the ajax is:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "AccountRecoveryQuestionsView",
    cache: false,
    data: $(questionForm).serialize(),
    success: function(data){
        $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse').text(data);
    },
    error: function(data) {
        $("#accountName").focus();
        //$('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse').text('An error occured validating the questions.');
        $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse').text(data);
    }
});
```

The error function is triggered; however, the message is not displayed.

I have changed the code to:

```
          statusCode: {
                400: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    alert(jqXHR.status);
                    alert(textStatus);
                    alert(errorThrown);
                    $("#accountName").focus();
                    $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse').text(errorThrown);
                }
            },
```

And the result is 400, error, blank.

I have changed the ajax to:

```
          .fail (function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(jqXHR.status);
                alert(textStatus);
                alert(errorThrown);
                alert(jqXHR.statusText);
                alert(jqXHR.responseText);
                $("#accountName").focus();
                //$('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse').text('An error occured validating the questions.');
                //$('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse').text(errorThrown);
                $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse').text(jqXHR.responseText);
            });
```

And alert(jqXHR.responseText); is returning:

```
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><title>HTTP Status [400] – [Bad Request]</title><style type="text/css">h1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} h2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} h3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} body {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} b {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} p {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;} a {color:black;} a.name {color:black;} .line {height:1px;background-color:#525D76;border:none;}</style></head><body><h1>HTTP Status [400] – [Bad Request]</h1><hr class="line" /><p><b>Type</b> Status Report</p><p><b>Message</b> Captcha description not correct</p><p><b>Description</b> The server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).</p><hr class="line" /><h3>Apache Tomcat/8.5.15</h3></body></html>
```

How do I just get the error message "Captcha description not correct". This is contained in the above.

Comment: `SC_BAD_REQUEST` is `400` and you should do: `$.ajax({
        statusCode: {
        400: function() { //do something }
        }
    });`

Comment: In regard of `#sendError`: "If the response has already been committed, this method throws an IllegalStateException. After using this method, the response should be considered to be committed and _should not be written to_."

Comment: Thanks @Aniket Sahrawat. This works. Is there a way to return a different error message for each exception as I have around five different exceptions that can occur (e.g., incorrect captcha name, question not answered correctly, email address not on file).

Comment: If you are throwing exceptions for them then it is not a correct way of handling client errors. You should just write a proper response code and message and send it back to the client whenever a client error occurred.

Comment: I am doing this statusCode: {
           400: function()
            {$('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse').text("Captch not correct.");}
          },

Comment: Is there a way to return a different error code for each type of error? Only one type of error will be returned. Or how do I return the error message?

Comment: Don't do that, instead map the response code inside your `error` function. Here is the example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6700873/6099347

Comment: Hi Aniket, I have made the change as edited above. The displayed is "400, error, blank".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HttpServletResponse` object should not be written to *after* `#sendError` has been called, as stated

> If the response has already been committed, this method throws an
>   IllegalStateException. After using this method, the response should be
>   considered to be committed and should not be written to.

hence:

```
response.sendError(...);
response.getWriter().write(...); // Should not be done
```

You should use the static field access of the error codes. In your code, you use `response.SC_BAD_REQUEST`, when you should use `HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST`. Writing the int code yourself, e.g. `sendError(400, ...)`, does not change the outcome.

The `.error` call for the `$.ajax`-function in jQuery, has been removed since version 3.0, so do not use it. Instead, you should use `.done`, `.fail` and `.always`. `.done` is the equivalent of `.success`, while `.fail` is the equivalent of `.error`, and `.always` is kinda like a `finally`-block in a try-catch (will, as the name implies, *always* run, regardless).

`$.ajax` always returns a jQuery XMLHttpRequest object, `jqXHR`. You can thus run method calls directly on the `$.ajax`-call, like

```
var jqxhrobj = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "AccountRecoveryQuestionsView",
    cache: false,
    data: $(questionForm).serialize()
})
.done(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    // Success here
    $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse').text(jqXHR.responseText);
})
.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    // Fail, do something about the error
    // Since you have several error codes you want to handle
    // you could for instance use a switch case
    switch(jqXHR.status) {
        case "400":
            // It might be an int, or even "400 Bad request",
            // change accordingly

            // Do something to handle the error
            break;
        default:
            // Handle errors not specified with a case
            break;
    }
});


// Later in the js code

jqxhrobj.always(function() {
    // Execute something here, regardless of success/failure of the $.ajax-call
});
```

Further information on the `jqXHR` object can be read [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR).

The responseText will contain a fully formatted html-output, with head, body and so on. If you look at the body of the responseText, it looks like this:

```
<body>
    <h1>HTTP Status [errorCode] – [errorCode description]</h1>
    <hr class="line" />
    <p><b>Type</b> Status Report</p>
    <p><b>Message</b> [message passed as 2nd argument in the sendError-call]</p>
    <p><b>Description</b> [full errorCode description]</p>
    <hr class="line" />
    <h3>Apache Tomcat/8.5.15</h3>
</body>
```

You could use `.find` (see [here](http://api.jquery.com/find/)) on the jqXHR.responseText - find the p-tags inside of the body. You should have 3 elements returned; the message will be inside the 2nd result element. You might want to do some sort of `substr`, to get rid of `<b>Message</b>`.

A simple but naive approach, that relies on the output to *always* have exactly the same structure:

```
var message = jqXHR.responseText.find("p:eq(1)").text();
// text() will not return the <b>-tags, just "Message [msg passed as argument]"
// We'll just substr from the end of "Message"
message = message.substr(7));
// Remove any leading/trailing whitespace
message = message.trim();
// message now contains the error message from #sendError
alert(message);
```

Comment: I have made the change. Please see my edit above. However, I am unable to get the error message to display. It is embedded in the long string of HTML.

Comment: I could replace "response.sendError(response.SC_BAD_REQUEST, "Captcha description not correct");" with "response.sendError(401, "Captcha description not correct");" using a different error code (e.g., 401. 402, 403) for each error test  use the case to test for each and display the appropriate error message. Is that a correct approach or a bad hack?

Comment: I've added a suggestion of how to get the error message, although it does not include a written example. If you need help with it, you'll have to ask. I also included information regarding the usage of the static fields (e.g. SC_BAD_REQUEST), at the top, after the code block with `response.sendError...`

Comment: I am having trouble starting on this. I have tried var message = $(jqXHR.responseText).find("p"); alert(message) and this returns "[object Object]".

Comment: I've added a rather naive, but acceptable approach.

Comment: A small btw: you do not have to add the jQuery-selector syntax `$()`, if you're handling a jQuery object (which jqXHR is in this case). You can just call any jQuery-related function against it, like you see in my example above, where I use the `find()` method.

Comment: How about "includes" is that acceptable: if(jqXHR.responseText.includes('Captcha description not correct')){
        $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse').text('Captcha description not correct');
       }else{
        $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse').text('An error occured.');
       }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167610/discussion-between-eli-and-glyn).

Answer (score 0):

Try to flush and close your writer

```
...
response.getWriter().flush();
response.getWriter().close();
```

If it didnt help, make `sendError` call the last one like this

```
response.getWriter().write("Captcha description incorrect.");
response.sendError(response.SC_BAD_REQUEST, "Captcha description not correct");
```

Comment: oh, I just realized, mb sendError is flushing the buffer, so you should make it last - see my update

Answer (score 0):

you can return the following

```
Response.status(500).entity("Captcha description incorrect. ").build();
```

Modify the error code based on your requirement,

Comment: Sorry harshita, this does not answer the OP. You seem to be lost by the wording in OP.